# Нужна помощь с Instagram API

Tags: php, веб-программирование, api, instagram, instagram-api

Кто знаком с Instagram API? Клиент вводит ссылку на свой профиль instagram и нужно получить информации о нем. Кто может подсказать?

Comment: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_self, но у них там не все функции доступны. Поэтому можно использовать https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API эту библиотеку.

Comment: Спасибо. А в запросе https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN  
что означает ACCESS-TOKEN? @entithat

Comment: Это токен, который нужно получить используя Ваш аккаунт для дальнейшего использования.. https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/

Comment: поробуйте это, в разы легче того, что описали выше. https://github.com/postaddictme/instagram-php-scraper